# VF Page with the Multi select picklists

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, multi-select, default-value

I am trying to use the multi select picklist field in my VF Page. The multi select picklist field has a default value, I was hoping when I use this field in the VF Page I should be able to see the default value in the `Chosen Table` the issue is it is not showing

```
<apex:outputPanel id="huSt" >
    <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(oppRec.Type__c,'hu'),true,false)}">
    <apex:inputField value="{!oppRec.Hu_St__c}" >
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="otherHU" status="status"/>
    </apex:inputField>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Where `Hu_St__c` is the multi select piicklist field with default

[image]

but in the VF Page this field is rendered default value doesnt show up in chosen section

[image]

Can anyone say what is missing here

Comment: N.B. `rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(oppRec.Type__c,'hu'),true,false)}"` can be simplified to `rendered="{!CONTAINS(oppRec.Type__c,'hu')}"`

Comment: @cropredy Sure will change it, Can you tell what could it be why on VF it doesnt show the default